# permission issue whith pip3 install numpy fails in virtualenv (ubuntu)

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, numpy, pip, virtualenv

I have not the permission to install numpy in a virtual environnement (ubuntu 14.04):

```
(DeepL)jeanpat@laptop:~$ pip3 install -U numpy
Downloading/unpacking numpy from https://pypi.python.org/packages/dd/9f/cd0ec9c50e4ed8650901ad4afde164e5252b6182a9e0c7bff5f8b4441960/numpy-1.11.1.zip#md5=5caa3428b24aaa07e72c79d115140e46
  Downloading numpy-1.11.1.zip (4.7MB): 4.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_jeanpat/numpy/setup.py) egg_info for package numpy
    Running from numpy source directory.

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.2
    Uninstalling numpy:
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 523, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy-1.8.2.egg-info' -> '/tmp/pip-0leid8xu-uninstall/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy-1.8.2.egg-info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1432, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 599, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1845, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 296, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/shutil.py", line 536, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy-1.8.2.egg-info'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/jeanpat/.pip/pip.log
```

Thats's weird, because numpy for python2 was installed as waited in :

```
/home/jeanpat/Developpements/DeepL/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
```

How to fix that problem? What is my error?

Comment: impossible to mix python2 and python3 in the same virtualenv ...

Comment: Since you have already activated the virtualenv, can't you just run `pip install -U numpy`?

Comment: pip install -U numpy is for python2 only, the problem comes with pip3. I have to setup an other virtualenv for python3.

Comment: If you are using `virtualenv`, that's not true. You still use `pip` in a virtualenv set up for Python 3.